# What is the process to show orders in the dashboard of my sandbox account?

Tags: php, android, square-connect

I'm working with sandbox enviroment and I can't see the orders created from my code.

I have the next process:

1. First in the android app I have the  "In-App Payments SDK" this returns me a nonce
2. Then I sent that nonce to a webservice in php (here i'm using this https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk)
3. Then inside my php server I create an order with one "line item ad hoc" it returns me a orderid
4. After that I create payment sending the nonce and the orderid
5. And That' all
6. the code in my android app is the same as the quickstart example

2.the code to create orders is:

```php
$body->setIdempotencyKey('.....');
$item=new \SquareConnect\Model\OrderLineItem();
$item->setName('test hamburger');
$item->setQuantity('1');
$money=new \SquareConnect\Model\Money();
$money->setAmount(1);
$money->setCurrency('USD');
$item->setBasePriceMoney($money);

$body->setLineItems([$item]);
$result = $apiInstance->createOrder($location_id, $body);
```

3. my code to create the payment is :

```php
$body->setAutocomplete(true);
$money=new \SquareConnect\Model\Money();
$money->setAmount(1);
$money->setCurrency('USD');
$body->setAmountMoney($money);
$body->setSourceId('NONCE I GOT from android');
$body->setOrderId('ORDERID I GOT FROM #2');
$result = $apiInstance->createPayment($body);
```

When I launch the "Default Test Account" I'm able to see the deposits and the transactions but when I go to the Orders it's empty.

so why my orders are not shown under the orders page (https://squareupsandbox.com/dashboard/orders/overview)?

Am I doing something wrong? is it supported in sandox?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

In order to view orders in Sandbox or in Production you have to include `fulfillments`: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/orders-api/create-orders#add-fulfillment-details

If there's no fulfillment details, then the order will not be displayed on your dashboard and is only retrievable via the API.